# How to determine the SQLite filename from an open connection?

Tags: php, sqlite, unit-testing

The PHP SQLite3 class doesn't contain the filename information, or provides a method to get the main file opened by the SQLite engine.

How to determine the filename?

This could be interesting in unit testing, to ensure the file used by the client matches the expected file from configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the SQLite3 class doesn't provide a property or a method to return this information, SQLite has a PRAGMA statement to get or set internal data or modify the library behavior.

```
PRAGMA database_list;
```

It will returns a row with seq, name, file fields respectively containing a sequence id, the internal name of the database and the path to the file:

```
0|main|/path/to/yourdatabasefile.db
```

Some details are interesting to note.

- A SQLite library could use several files.
- The path will be canonical, and so follows symbolic links.

**Unit testing case sample:**

To test if the current $client connection file matches $config->databaseFilename:

```
/**
 * Tests the SQLite client connection
 */
function testClient () {
    $client = ...
    $config = ...
    $row = $client->query("PRAGMA database_list")->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
    $this->assertEquals(
        [
            'seq' => 0,
            'name' => 'main',
            'file' => realpath($config->databaseFilename)
        ],
        $row,
        "The query PRAGMA database_list didn't return what we expected: one database opened by the client, the file returned by the database matching our configuration file."
    );
}
```

To test if a query returns the expected result, an efficient method is to compare two arrays, one with expected result, one with the row returned by fetchArray.

By default, fetchArray stores twice each field value, one with a numeric index, one with an associativekey. Here we focus on the fields containing the right information, so we use SQLITE3_ASSOC parameter to get an associative content only. If you wish to test the order, use fetchArray(SQLITE3_NUM):

```
    $row = $client->query("PRAGMA database_list")->fetchArray(SQLITE3_NUM);
    $this->assertEquals(
        [0, 'main', realpath($config->databaseFilename)]
        $row,
        "The query PRAGMA database_list didn't return what we expected: one database opened by the client, the file returned by the database matching our configuration file."
    );
```

The realpath function is used to get a canonical path.

**References:**

- [PRAGMA statements documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html)
- [PHPUnit assertEquals test](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertEquals)
- [PHP realpath($path) documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)
- [PHP SQLite3Result::fetchArray($mode) documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php)